# Workshop register web with Django

Tags: python, django

I want create workshop registration web with Django.
I am using User default model of Django also create this model for save workshop lists of every users:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    workshop = models.ManyToManyField(Workshop,null=True)
```

but I don't know how can I use this model in my view.py in order to registered user can register for workshop.

Thank you for your help.
Hamed

Answer (score 0):

First, Please make sure that you do the complete [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/)

This is kind of tricky because you must [create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#user-objects) a user first THen create the user profile.  The documentation on the user model explains it the best, but it will look something like

```
user = User.objects.create_user('john', 'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'johnpassword')
new_profile = UserProfile(user=user)
new_profile.save()
```

Additionally, you might want to look at `OneToOneField` instead of foreign key because it provides an additional way to access the related object

Also, if EVERY new user needs a UserProfile it might be beneficial to use a user create signal so that a `UserProfile` is automatically created

did you check out the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/)